# OpenMP Threads not fully utilize CPU cores on new machine

Tags: c++, multithreading, fortran, openmp

I have a multi-threaded application that solves huge matrix in parallel. I recently changed my laptop and start getting some weird behavior on the new laptop. The processor in the old laptop was **11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-11950H** and the new laptop has **12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12900H**. When running my multi-threaded application (using 4 threads) on the old laptop I am seeing these threads taking over 4 cores and fully utilizing them, and the overall CPU usage is around 50% since the laptop has 8 physical cores. Please see picture below:
[image]

When running the same application using the same (exactly the same) executable binary I am seeing only one core fully utilized and the rest are at around 10%-20% and the overall CPU usage is under 15%. Please see the following picture:
[image]

Is there any explanation on why the same binary is running on one machine and not running on the other machine?

Notes:

- I am using OpenMP to start threads
- I tried to set the priority of the threads to high but it didn't help

Note:
On the laptop that has 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12900H, I disabled the E cores from the BIOS to make sure threads only got assigned to P cores and that didn't fix the problem. Please see below:
[image]

From the picture above we can see that only thread 1 fully utilizes its CPU.

The following is the way I am launching my threads:

```
    CALL OMP_SET_NUM_THREADS(4)
    !$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(i)  
    DO i = 1, 4, 1
        CALL solve_axb_r_submat(n, A, line_A, X, B, flag, i, submatrix_number, Fkluunit(i))
    END DO
    !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

The above code is being called more than 20000 times, so every iteration called a function that has the piece of code above. I am working on windows with Visual studio 2022 and OpeApi 2023. The following is some of my project property:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Please note the command line we added to determine the affinity of the threads in the last image. When we added that we see that threads are pinned on the same core and not moving between cores.

Comment: Have you simply checked that the application actually launches 4 threads? Where is the number of threads set (in your code, environment variable...)?

Comment: Yes, I verified that the application launches 4 threads. The number of threads is set in the code. I also can see these threads in the second picture above.

Comment: One answer guess did not solve your problem. To enable more than wild guessing, please show the code, a [mcve], your system configuration and the commands you are using to compile and launch the code.

Comment: Vladimir, thanks for your response. I just added the part of the code where I launched my threads and the project properties.

Comment: Can you try using different cores? Note that there are OpenMP environment variables for this, you do not need the compile-time options. Look for `OMP_PROC_BIND` and `OMP_PLACES` and `OMP_DISPLAY_AFFINITY` at https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpch6.html#openmpse52.html

Comment: Note you should avoid using the runtime function `OMP_SET_NUM_THREADS` manually, especially if it is in a loop (at it is harder for OpenMP runtimes to make some optimizations during the initialization of the parallel loop). You can use the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` for that. Besides, since your loop only have 4 iterations for 4 threads, it should be better to use a `schedule(static)` here (although it should be the default one in practice).

Comment: A VTune analysis (e.g. schedule) would be particularly helpful here (especially since it looks like you already use the Intel tools) in addition to what Vladimir suggested (especially having the source code -- including the content of `solve_axb_r_submat`). Trying to tune the `OMP_WAIT_POLICY` can help to see if the active core is actually waiting other threads.

Answer (score 6):

The i9-11950H processor is a Tiger-Lake processor while the i9-12900H is an Alder-Lake processor. The main difference is that Alder-Lake has a Big-Little architecture while the former is uniform (and far more mainstream). In practice, this means there are two sets of cores: big cores which are fast but energetically inefficient, and little cores which are energetically efficient but slow. This architecture is pretty interesting on notebook machines so to provide a good trade-off between performance and power consumption. Efficient cores can also help to improve the overall performance of the CPU in some specific cases. The bad news is that **such an architecture is poorly supported by many runtimes and applications so far**. One main issue is the **load imbalance** caused by the different kind of cores. Indeed, 1 thread running on a performance core generally run faster than the one on an efficient core for the same workload. The faster thread shall wait for the others so **the overall computation is bound by the slow cores**. I guess this is what happens here : 1 core is intensively uses, while 3 others are just barely used and others are IDLE. My hypothesis is that the core used intensively is an efficient core while others are performance cores (waiting for the slow one).

You can request OpenMP to use a dynamic scheduling so to automatically load-balance the work between the different cores. This has an additional overhead but it is likely better in this case. One way is to use the `schedule(dynamic)` clause on parallel for loops. Another way is to tweak the environment variable [`OMP_SCHEDULE`](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse49.html).

Alternatively, you can bind the OpenMP threads yourself so to use the same kind of cores. You can do that by changing the environment variables `OMP_PROC_BIND` and `OMP_PLACES` This should be what the OS is supposed to do automatically, but it looks like it fails (or this is not actually the issue)...

Comment: Jérôme- thanks for your response. Is there a way to tell which cores are big cores and which are little?

Comment: Yes. However, I am not sure this is possible with the task manager (I am not very familiar with Windows and do not have such kind of processor). AFAIK, tools like AIDA64 should be able to track kind of core and their usage at the same time.

Comment: Besides, low-level profiling tools like VTune can help to see the load imbalance assuming this is coming from this. This is a good idea to use it both to confirm/infirm the hypothesis and get a lot of useful information if the hypothesis turns out not to be correct. You can see the OpenMP threads waiting time in orange on the timeline if they are spin-waiting assuming the wait-policy is active. With a passive wait-policy, you should see that most threads are not schedule meanwhile one is computing.

Comment: The new CPU has 6 performance cores and 8 efficient cores: why only one efficient core would be at 100%?

Comment: PierU- this is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: @PierU Some OpenMP runtimes (eg. IOMP) bind threads to core by default and this binding is sometime broken on unusual/new architectures (especially non-uniform ones). It happens on 3 different (HPC) architectures so far. Having such a binding is quite surprising but this is the best explanation I have so far base on the provided information (and so why I promote checking the hypothesis and retrieve additional informations otherwise).

Comment: For the LLVM, AFAIK, they use hw-loc for the binding and it looks like hw-loc only support big-little architecture experimentally [since recently](https://github.com/open-mpi/hwloc/pull/432) using a new API. This means the OpenMP code should have been modified even more recently. The OpenMP runtime/compiler needs to be up-to-date to avoid issues like this. For GCC, AFAIK, they use a custom hard-wired approach.

Comment: I tried making the OpenMP binding dynamic and didn't help, and I also tried to disable the E cores to make sure we only used the P cores and that didn't work as well. Please see the picture I posted at the end of the question above

Comment: Ok. It looks like the hypothesis is wrong. I plan to delete this answer soon (unless I find an update explaining that).

Comment: @JérômeRichard I don't think that the LLVM OpenMP runtime (used by the Intel compilers) binds threads (either to logical CPUs, cores, or sockets) by default. You can ask it to by setting OMP_PROC_BIND or KMP_AFFINITY...